# One dodgy lamp: Differential is triggered and several separate circuit breakers become differential-triggering. How is that even possible?

Tags: electrical-panel

I had a bit of a phenomenon on the neighbour's electrical circuit.

What was observed:

- The differential had blown

What was tried:

- I tried to to isolate the faulty circuit by trying to get the differential stay closed.
- Trial and error resulted in several circuit breakers set to "open" until this was managed, with no obvious pattern. For example, the circuit breaker for the fridge and the circuit breaker for the oven both had to be "open". Closing them would trip the differential. Even then, the differential randomly tripped after maybe 5 minutes of stability.

What fixed it:

- The neighbor remembered a dodgy lamp plugged in. It was indeed doddy, as the power supply was broken open with the transformer spool clearly visible and the grounding cable had broken loose.
- After unplugging said lamp, all the ciruit breakers could be closed and the differential could be satisfactorily closed and stayed this way.
- I'm not sure whether I "isolated" that lamp through opening one of the ciruit breakers earlier, but probably yes (judging from the inscriptions on the breakers at least).

Question:

How is it possible that a single device on the "power plug" circuit causes the circuit breaker of the "stove" or "fridge" circuit to become differential-triggering-when-closed?

I actually suspected a major problem with the cabling at first, like water intrusion or a rat having a final meal. I reckon one should have a professional take a good look at this phenomenon?

Comment: You'll need to tell us what country, and if not North America, whether you have 1-phase or 3-phase power in the building.   Normally I can infer it from the text, but not this time.

Comment: This is an Eurozone setup: Luxembourg to be precise. 3-phase power: yes. But I will have to take a closer look at that panel and/or watch the screaming electrician when he drops by on Thursday.

Comment: I'm guessing that a differential is the same as an RCD, similar to an American GFCI?

Answer (score 3):

**The lamp likely had a neutral-to-ground leak.**

First of all, some context for those not familiar with how things are commonly arranged at least in late-90s western/central EU homes. There's typically three-phase 230V/400V service passing through a three-phase RCD (GFCI) breaker. There's one such device per panel or one for the whole house, often doing double duty as the main breaker/shutoff. The load side of that GFCI is then fed to all the branch circuit breakers in the panel (via short patch wires or "combs", which is the DIN-rail-analogue of a bus bar, feeding a single phase to every third breaker on the rail).

A 3-phase RCD works almost like a plain single-phase GFCI, except that it calculates the sum of L1+L2+L3 phase currents, subtracts the neutral current from that, and trips if the result is significantly nonzero (30 mA).

Normally, there's only one neutral-ground bond on the line (upstream) side of the RCD. However, if a device downstream develops a neutral-ground short, the RCD will trip as some part of the neutral current will be diverted around the RCD and the currents will no longer add up. Given that the ground path is required to have a very low impedance (and measuring it is often required to pass inspection), a hard neutral-ground short will often trip the RCD reliably, but smaller leaks might not. (The leak current then depends on the instantaneous voltage of the neutral wire with respect to ground at the point of the faulty device, which depends on the current flowing through said section of the neutral, and is thus influenced by which devices are turned on, where they are physically placed and from which phases they are fed. I guess you can now imagine that debugging these issues can be *loads of fun*. Sometimes, you will see the RCD trip when some random device turns *off*, because it decreases the load on L3 so that it no longer compensates the L1+L2 loads on the neutral, making the neutral float a little bit away from 0 V and making the leak current exceed the RCD threshold.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a neutral-to-ground short in the lamp, which is not disconnected by opening its breaker, is creating a current path impacting other circuits.  I can't say exactly how as I don't know exactly how the multiple RCDs on a panel interact with one another through their common ground and neutral bus.  But it's the only possible explanation.  I'm guessing you are in a home with European-style RCD groups controlling everything in the house, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The electrical panel is not top quality work but it should be "european standard" ca. 1998. I will definitely have a professional look at that.

Comment: I don't think a neutral-ground fault on one RCD should cause a trip on another one.  I don't really know that, but if the lamp is causing this while its breaker is off, then clearly, EITHER, it is normal for such a trip to occur in this circumstance, or you have BOTH something wrong with your lamp and something wrong with your wiring.  Maybe for example the RCD neutral buses are not isolated correctly.

Comment: @jay613 If two RCDs are cross-connected *to each other*, I would expect a double trip. A typical reason for that would be "borrowing a neutral".

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica sorry I'm learning this ... shouldn't borrowing a neutral from the wrong RCD cause a trip immediately even without any additional faults?

Comment: @jay only if there's current flow on the neutral, i.e. if a load is making use of the neutral.

Comment: I think I'll make this answer a comment if I can't think of SOME specific way that a neutral borrowed from a different RCD, or some other wiring fault, would fail to trip any RCD in normal use but would cause tripping given a faulty device even with the device switched off at the breaker.  I said "creating a current path" which I guess is a little too obvious.   I'd like SOME plausible scenario even if it isn't OP's.     I tried sketching a few scenarios, I can easily create OP's situation on paper but then I trip EVERYTHING in normal use even with the bad lamp unplugged.